# SQl to XML create node

Tags: sql, xml

I have a flat table that I'm trying to turn into an xml output .

I need the address part to appear in a separate node.

```
Select ID,AddressLine1,PostCode,Price,Name from Property
```

I need this to appear like

```
<Property>
   <ID> 1 <ID>
   <Address> 
      <Line1>10 Downing Street</Line1>
      <PostCode>SW11SW</Postcode>
   </Address> 
   <Price> 1,000,000,000 <Price>
   <Name> My Next House<Name>
</Property>
```

any ideas how I achieve the address part?

Thanks
Sp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you are using MS SQL Server, using FOR XML PATH, try this code:

```
DECLARE @Property TABLE (ID INT, [AddressLine1] VARCHAR(30), PostCode VARCHAR(7),
                         Price MONEY, [Name] VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @Property
SELECT 1,'10 Downing Street','SW11SW',1000000000,'My Next House'

SELECT ID, AddressLine1 AS 'Address/AddressLine1', PostCode AS 'Address/Postcode',
       Price, Name 
  FROM @Property 
   FOR XML PATH('Property'), ELEMENTS
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server? By using `for xml path, elements`

```
Select 
    ID,
    AddressLine1 as 'Address/Line1',
    PostCode as 'Address/Postcode',
    Price,
    Name 
from Property 
for xml path, elements
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885